# How can I split my hiera config by role?

Tags: puppet, hiera

I'm using hiera to assign classes like `webserver` or `dbserver` to my nodes. The `webserver` class just includes apache and sets some config on it (e.g. port). Obviously I don't want to replicate this config for every node, so I put it in common.yaml. However, my common.yaml is getting big, so I want to split it up. I'd like to have one file containing the config for the `webserver` role, another for the `dbserver` role etc. I'm imagining my hiera.yaml to look something like this:

```
:hierarchy:
  - "fqdn/%{::fqdn}"
  - "role/%{ROLE}"
  - common
```

Where the `role` folder would contain files like `webserver.yaml`, `appserver.yaml`, `dbserver.yaml`. I've seen various blog posts saying that the solution is to create a custom 'role' fact, but most of them achieve this by loading that fact from a file on the agent node (e.g from `/etc/role`), which to me seems to defeat the point of puppet (I use puppet specifically so I don't have to log into each node and change some config every time I want it to have some new role).

To be clear, I don't want to have to edit files on the agent to get this to work, I want it all done using the config that's on the master.

I guess I could have something like the following and exhaustively list every role as an element in the hierarchy, but that doesn't seem that manageable.

```
:hierarchy:
  - "fqdn/%{::fqdn}"
  - "webserver"
  - "appserver"
  - "dbserver"
  - common
```

Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

To be able to use `$Role` in your hiera config, it needs to be supplied as a fact/variable, however there is a way to do this on the master instead of on the node. This is one of the things that [External Node Classifiers](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/external_nodes.html) can be used for.

Basically, you need to write a script that takes the node name and prints out yaml that includes the `Role` parameter's value. For example, you could have one yaml file that is just a map of node names to roles, and then the script does a lookup and prints the result (as a parameter in the linked schema). Here is [an example](https://github.com/Zetten/puppet-hiera-enc).

There are also more robust ENC's out there, if you are interested in new tooling. For example, [Foreman](http://theforeman.org/) gives you a web interface for grouping hosts together into similar roles, setting parameters to inject into puppet runs, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I've come up with a solution for this. Only disadvantage is that the max number of roles is hardcoded. This will be better with hiera 3 until then try this:

/etc/puppet/hiera.yaml

```
 ---
:backends:
  - yaml
:yaml:
  :datadir: /etc/puppet/hieradata
:hierarchy:
  - 'nodes/%{::clientcert}'
  - 'roles/%{::role_4}'
  - 'roles/%{::role_3}'
  - 'roles/%{::role_2}'
  - 'roles/%{::role_1}'
  - common
```

/etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp

```
# Get roles
$roles = hiera_array('roles', [])

# Declare Roles in vars (not needed in puppet 4)
$role_1 = $roles[0]
$role_2 = $roles[1]
$role_3 = $roles[2]
$role_4 = $roles[3]

# Include Classes
hiera_include('classes')
```

/etc/puppet/hieradata/roles/webserver.yaml

```
---
classes:
  - nginx

# put nginx config here
```

/etc/puppet/hieradata/nodes/your_node_name.yaml

```
---
roles:
 - webserver

classes:
# put node specific stuff here
```