# Puppet - Multiple Roles in Hiera

Tags: puppet, hiera

I'm trying (and struggling) to get a (multiple) role model implemented in Hiera.

I've worked in the last 2 years with exact the same model as a user and now want to rebuild the same structure on my own. For example, my node.yaml should contain only the roles I want to apply onto the host:

/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/nodes/my.host.de.yaml

`classes:
  - ydixken_baseinstall
  - additional_modules
[...]`

For me it's way more intuitive, to place a yaml in the roles/ directory, with the name of the role, and avoid dealing with profiles:

/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/roles/ydixken_baseinstall.yaml

`classes:
  - apt
  - unattended_upgrades
  - [...]
apt::update:
  frequency: 'daily'
  loglevel: 'debug'
[...]`

Placing the role definitions as a node fact is not practicable for me. It's also nice-to-have to allow a customization of the already defined values inside of the node configuration, if needed.

Right now my directory, hiera.yaml & file-structure looks like this:

/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/hiera.yaml

`version: 5
defaults:
  datadir:  /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production
  data_hash: yaml_data
hierarchy:
  - name: "Per-node data (yaml version)"
    paths:
     - "nodes/%{fqdn}.yaml"
     - "roles/%{role}.yaml"
     - common`

/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/hiera.yaml

`version: 5
defaults:
hierarchy:
  - name: "FQDN"
    path: "nodes/%{fqdn}.yaml"
  - name: "Roles"
    path: "roles/%{role}.yaml"
  - name: "Common Data"
    path: "common.yaml"`

/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/manifests/site.pp

`hiera_include('classes')`

How can i achieve this?

My current error:

`Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER: Server Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Function Call, Could not find class ::ydixken_baseinstall for my.host.de (file: /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/manifests/site.pp, line: 1, column: 1) on node my.host.de`

Comment: "How can i achieve this?" What is "this"? Everything you described works fine as is.

Comment: No, it does not - sorry, i forgot to attach the error:

`Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER: Server Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Function Call, Could not find class ::ydixken_baseinstall for my.host.de (file: /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/manifests/site.pp, line: 1, column: 1) on node my.host.de`

Comment: Then the class is missing from your modulepath, or you have some other code environment error on your master that exists outside the information provided.

Comment: Please have a look at my text - the class name should be identical to the role name. Putting everything from the role definition into the node definition lets it work as expected. There's a similar thread requesting more or less the same, but the solution posted does not work anymore with puppet 4 and hiera 5: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30255251/how-can-i-split-my-hiera-config-by-role/35367856#35367856

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found exactly, what i was looking for: [r10k](https://techpunch.co.uk/development/how-to-build-a-puppet-repo-using-r10k-with-roles-and-profiles)